# Infinite loop when layoutIfNeeded called

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a method that, via some delegate, manage my app base animation (UIAnimateWithDuration).
This method works fine for so long, everywhere in my app. After updating to Xcode 9, the method still works but in one controller it doesn't.
It seems to generate an infinite loop with the following message:

> warning: could not execute support code to read Objective-C class data in the process. This may reduce the quality of type information available.

when `[self.view layoutIfNeeded]` called.

Here the snippet:

```
//MyTableViewDelegate.m
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0.) {
        [self.presenter gestureAnimationWithConstant:scrollView.contentOffset.y alpha:__alphaMaxContainer];
        return;
    }
}

//MyPresenter.m
-(void)gestureAnimationWithConstant:(float)y alpha:(double)alpha{
    [self.view animationOnScrollingWith:y];
}

//MyViewController.m
-(void)animationOnScrollingWith:(float)constant{
    self.constraint.constant += 1;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded]; //here it fires infinite loop

    if (self.constraint.constant > - (self.containerView.frame.size.height-10)){
        [self constraintAnimationWithAlpha:constant alpha:__maxAlphaContainer enableGesture:NO];
    }
}

-(void)constraintAnimationWithAlpha:(float)constant alpha:(double)alpha enableGesture:(BOOL)enableGesture{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 delay:0.0 usingSpringWithDamping:1.0 initialSpringVelocity:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        self.constraint.constant = constant;
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        [self changeTopSectionAlphaValue:alpha];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        if (enableGesture)
            self->__gesture.enabled = YES;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }];
}
```

Any idea? I'm going mad!

Comment: Can you update with the call of animationOnScrollingWith(_:) please ?

Comment: If there is an infinite loop, you may have more info by checking the callstack: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3sIA.png ?

Comment: from where you are calling animationOnScrollingWith?